# How do you specify the order of the shard key fields in pymongo? (for mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How do you specify the order of the shard key fields in pymongo? (for mongodb)

Basically, pymongo allowed you to do:

```
connection.admin.command('shardcollection', 'dbname.collname', key = {c:1,b:1,a:1})
```

but this doesn't respect the order of my keys.

If you do this in the mongo shell, it respected the order of the keys.

Anyone know how to specify the order in pymongo?

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out!

```
from collections import OrderedDict

key = OrderedDict([('a',1), ('b', 1), ('c',1)])
...
...
connection.admin.command('shardcollection', 'mydb.test', key=key)
```

Comment: oops ! I didn't see its you who posted the answer. By the way its not working for me. It says "missing values". Any idea ?

Comment: try a list of tuples like [('c', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 1) ]